# How can I apply a VBA macro to multiple docx files?

Tags: vba, ms-word, docx

I would like to apply a VBA Macro to multiple docx files. My macro find a text with a specific font and then hide it.

This is the macro that works when you execute it on a single docx file :

```
Sub color()

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Fnd As Boolean

G:
    Set Rng = ActiveDocument.Range
    Rng.Find.ClearFormatting
    Rng.Find.Font.color = RGB(191, 191, 191)
    Rng.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

    With Rng.Find
    .Text = ""
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .Execute
     Fnd = .Found
    End With
    If Fnd = True Then
        With Rng
            .MoveStart wdWord, 0
            .Select
            With .Font
                .Hidden = True
            End With
        End With
        GoTo G
    End If

End Sub
```

And I've found a macro on a forum that can loop on all files in a folder and I've combined to mine  :

```
Sub Documentos()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim strFolder As String, strFile As String, strDocNm As String, wdDoc As Document
strDocNm = ActiveDocument.FullName: strFolder = GetFolder
If strFolder = "" Then Exit Sub
strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\*.docx", vbNormal)
While strFile <> ""
  If strFolder & "\" & strFile <> strDocNm Then
    Set wdDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=strFolder & "\" & strFile, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
    With wdDoc
      Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Fnd As Boolean

G:
    Set Rng = ActiveDocument.Range
    Rng.Find.ClearFormatting
    Rng.Find.Font.color = RGB(191, 191, 191)
    Rng.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

    With Rng.Find
    .Text = ""
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .Execute
     Fnd = .Found
    End With
    If Fnd = True Then
        With Rng
            .MoveStart wdWord, 0
            .Select
            With .Font
                .Hidden = True
            End With
        End With
        GoTo G
    End If
      .Close SaveChanges:=True
    End With
  End If
  strFile = Dir()
Wend
Set wdDoc = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


Function GetFolder() As String
Dim oFolder As Object
GetFolder = ""
Set oFolder = CreateObject("Shell.Application").BrowseForFolder(0, "Choose a folder", 0)
If (Not oFolder Is Nothing) Then GetFolder = oFolder.Items.Item.Path
Set oFolder = Nothing
End Function
```

When I execute this macro, I opens the document but does nothing.

Can someone help to combine them ?

Comment: Here are links to two free utilities for running macros on all files in a folder. http://www.gmayor.com/document_batch_processes.htm and https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/process_batch_folder_addin.html.

Answer (score 0):

Use the tools already built into Word.

A much simpler route to do that same effect is to create a Word character style with gray shading and apply that to all text that is to have a grey background. Then you can change all instances to a clear background by simply changing the style definition:

```
Sub ChangeShadedTextStyle()
    ActiveDocument.Styles("Shaded Text").Font.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried to run the code with your modifications and word crashes after the execution. I've tried to debug and add `DoEvents` to prevent Microsoft from crashing but I think that the macro loops endlessly. I've tried to change `.Wrap = wdFindContinue` to `.Wrap = wdFindStop` but doesn't work either...

Comment: It's not crashing here. What is it supposed to do? I can't test if I don't know your expected result.

Comment: Is supposed to hide all the text in "gray" on my doc. I think that I've found the problem, a lot of my docs are actually fulfilled with tables. Is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: I've completely revised my answer to a much simpler solution. Always include your goal in your question, it let's others supply outside-of-the-box solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's because of `Set Rng = ActiveDocument.Range`. in the loop you set Rng to active document. open a file doesn't make it activated automatically. And I see you have already assigned the opened file to wdDoc. Maybe use 'Set Rng = .Range' instead. see if it works for you.